# Read and write tbz file in PHP

Tags: php, fopen, tar, fwrite

Hi I want to download a file that is in tbz format. So I first need to download tbz file so I am first reading it and writing to local directory on my server using the following code:

```
ini_set("memory_limit","15M");
set_time_limit(1600);

if($result){
$write_handle=fopen("temp/$filename", 'a');
while (!feof($handle)) {
  $contents = fread($handle, 8192);
  echo "<pre>";
  echo strlen($contents);
  echo time()-$time_start;
  echo "</pre>";
  fwrite($write_handle, $contents);
}
echo $contents;
fclose($write_handle);    
}
```

And the files is there but when I try to tar -xjf command of linux on it, it says :
`Unexpected EOF in archive`. So what can be problem?

I actually need to use the file inside that tbz file so is there a way to do so. File size is almost more than 1GB.

Comment: Is there any thing more required to read and write a tbz file? or it should be fine like normal text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmz, you only give a part of your code, but reading your issue and considering you said:
**File size is almost more than 1GB.**
I have to ask..

Are you using [set_time_limit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) so the scripts lasts long enough and [memory_limit in php.ini](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) so the script has enough memory?

Comment: ini_set("memory_limit","15M");
    set_time_limit(1600);

Comment: I have updated code and this don't seems to be memory limit problem as file is uploaded there and its size on my server is more than 1GB as expected

Comment: So both time limit and memory works? I have found that ini_set can be buggy at times (especially with memory_limit). You sure error reporting isn't off and any other errors would show up ?

Comment: Also, re-checked your code. Wouldn't it be safer to use [the copy function?](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) ?

Comment: As you can see I am doing echo after fread and fwrite loop and that is executing fine so I don't think that there can be any error that is not displaying. Instead it seems that some thing more is required in writing tbz file like some header e.t.c.?

Comment: Wait. What's in `temp/$filename`?! It's not another tbz file ?

Comment: It is now working fine and may be some time limit , I have extended it more and it is now working fine . Thanks

Comment: Hah, it was set_time_limit(), uhu for Simplicity. :D